# convertir un array de un json anidado en objeto

Tags: c#, json

me gustaria poder navegar sobre el json siguiente (adjunto solo una parte):

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "acceptance_decision_date": null,
            "can_cancel": false,
            "can_shop_ship": false,
            "channel": {
                "code": "eciStore",
                "label": "ECI - España"
            },
            "commercial_id": "00100900625887820210804074424_1",
            "created_date": "2021-08-04T06:03:03Z",
            "currency_iso_code": "EUR",
            "customer": {
                "billing_address": null,
                "civility": null,
                "customer_id": "0284718996",
                "firstname": "nombre",
                "lastname": "apellido",
                "locale": null,
                "shipping_address": null
            },
```

A nivel de código, para iterar sobre los distintos registros, utilizo las siguientes líneas:

```
string responseBody = objReader.ReadToEnd();
JObject objeto = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
IList<JToken> results = objeto["orders"].Children().ToList();
                              
foreach (var p in results)
{
Orders X = new Orders();
X.acceptance_decision_date = p["acceptance_decision_date"].ToString();
X.can_cancel = Convert.ToBoolean(p["can_cancel"]); 
X.can_shop_ship = Convert.ToBoolean(p["can_shop_ship"]);

X.commercial_id = p["commercial_id"].ToString();
X.created_date = Convert.ToDateTime(p["created_date"]);
X.currency_iso_code = p["currency_iso_code"].ToString();
```

todo esto me va bien, pero no consigo entrar en la dimensión de Customer.
La clase la tengo definida de este modo.

```
public class Orders
    {
        public object acceptance_decision_date { get; set; }
        public bool can_cancel { get; set; }
        public bool can_shop_ship { get; set; }
        public Channel channel { get; set; }
        public string commercial_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
        public string currency_iso_code { get; set; }
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
```

Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda por favor.

Gracias,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola Xapogo tu respuesta esta muy bien, no le veo nada de malo; Sin embargo pudieras mejorarlo utilizando clases y el nuget Newtonsoft.Json te explico como:

1. Puedes utilizar la pagina https://json2csharp.com/ para convertir tu JSON en clases de C#
   [image: json2csharp.com para convertir json a c# clases]
2. Agrega el nuget de Newtonsoft.json a tu proyecto:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Utiliza la clase para deserializar el json `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

   ```
   using Newtonsoft.Json;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var jsonString = @"{
           ""orders"": [
               {
                   ""acceptance_decision_date"": null,
                   ""can_cancel"": false,
                   ""can_shop_ship"": false,
                   ""channel"": {
                       ""code"": ""eciStore"",
                       ""label"": ""ECI - España""
                   },
                   ""commercial_id"": ""00100900625887820210804074424_1"",
                   ""created_date"": ""2021-08-04T06:03:03Z"",
                   ""currency_iso_code"": ""EUR"",
                   ""customer"": {
                       ""billing_address"": null,
                       ""civility"": null,
                       ""customer_id"": ""0284718996"",
                       ""firstname"": ""nombre"",
                       ""lastname"": ""apellido"",
                       ""locale"": null,
                       ""shipping_address"": null
                   }
               }]
       }";
       var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);

       foreach(var order in root?.orders)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"===============================================");
           Console.WriteLine($"                Order Info");
           Console.WriteLine($"===============================================");
           Console.WriteLine($"Order Id:{order.commercial_id}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Date:{order.created_date:dd-MM-yyyy}");
           Console.WriteLine($"===============================================");
           Console.WriteLine($"                Cuestomer Info");
           Console.WriteLine($"===============================================");
           Console.WriteLine($"Customer Id:{order.customer?.customer_id}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Full name:{order.customer?.firstname} {order.customer?.lastname}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Billing Address:{order.customer?.billing_address}");
       }
   }
   }

   public class Root
   {
       public List<Order> orders { get; set; }
   }

   public class Channel
   {
       public string code { get; set; }
       public string label { get; set; }
   }

   public class Customer
   {
       public object billing_address { get; set; }
       public object civility { get; set; }
       public string customer_id { get; set; }
       public string firstname { get; set; }
       public string lastname { get; set; }
       public object locale { get; set; }
       public object shipping_address { get; set; }
   }

   public class Order
   {
       public object acceptance_decision_date { get; set; }
       public bool can_cancel { get; set; }
       public bool can_shop_ship { get; set; }
       public Channel channel { get; set; }
       public string commercial_id { get; set; }
       public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
       public string currency_iso_code { get; set; }
       public Customer customer { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que puedas revisar este ejemplo y te pueda ser util, saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Cristina. Tu respuesta me ha sido muy útil!

Comment: Genial, si tienes algun otra detalle no dudes en preguntarme, saludos

Answer (score 1):

lo he resuelto de este modo, pero no se si es correcto.

```
customer.billing_address = p["customer"]["billing_address"].ToString();
customer.civility = p["customer"]["civility"].ToString();
customer.customer_id = p["customer"]["customer_id"].ToString();
```